# java while loop not breaking out

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, infinite-loop

So I am writing a program where somebody draws cards from a deck. So I wrote a while loop that loops through and checks to see if there are over 4 of the randomly created card drawn, and if there is, change the card.

here is my code:

```
String card = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random() * 13) + " ";
String[] used2 = used.split(" ");
//used is a String like "12 3 7 8 4 ... # etc" such that it is all the previously drawn cards.
boolean checking = true;
boolean isIn = false;
int in = 0;
int check = 0;
while(checking){
    for(int q = 0; q < used2.length; q++){
        check += 1;
        if(card.equals(used2[q] + " ")){
            in += 1;
            if(in == 4){
                System.out.println(check); //debugging line
                check += 1;
                card = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random() * 13) + " ";
                card_val = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random() * 13);
                isIn = true;
                in = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(isIn){
        //will execute if there is 4 of the cards already drawn so the while loop continues with a different card
        checking = true;
    }
    else{
        //breaks out of while loop because the card can be drawn
        checking = false;
    }
}
used += card;
```

Now this runs, but when I put it inside a for loop and set it to run like 40 times, about 2/3 times it creates an of infinite loop.

I discovered that the infinite loop is only created if the `if(in == 4)` statement comes out to be true.

Why is this? I have been debugging since last night and I cannot figure this out.

Comment: A cleaner way of writing your `if-else` statement: `checking = isIn;`

Comment: Because you set `isIn` to `true` in that block, which means `checking` will never get set to `false`.

Comment: Also a comment to `(int)Math.ceil(Math.random() * 13) + " "`. I suspect your reason for `" "` is to convert the int to String, however you can only do `+""` which makes the code simpler afterwards..

Comment: @KubaSpatny: I am not sure what you mean by that

Comment: @RyanSaxe well what is the reason for the `+" "`?

Answer (score 6):

Once you set `isIn` to `true`, you never set it back to `false`.  So, the `if` statement at the bottom will keep setting `checking` to `true`, resulting in an infinite loop.

Set `isIn` to `false` at the beginning of the `while` loop.

```
while(checking){
    isIn = false;  // Add this line.
    for(int q = 0; q < used2.length; q++){
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a complex algorithm for a simple task.

Why not change the implementation to use simple subtraction? Initially allocate a `List` of all 52 values, then as you "draw" cards out of the deck, remove it from the list.

Then you can use `Math.random() * list.size()` to get an appropriately-ranged index?

Comment: I haven't learned lists yet, this is a hw problem, we haven't even learned arrays, I've just known the split method so I used it to make manipulating the string easier